# AES/CBC Decryption not working as expected

Tags: java, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I'm having some issued decrypting data using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in Java.
I am encrypting two values A and B and then data from a file. The encrypted values are written in file in the described sequence.
When decrypting the bytes for the respective pieces are properly located (confirmed via debugging) and the inputs to the decrypting functions are correct, no padding issues there.

Encryption code:

```
byte[] iv = {..........};

IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, fileKey, ivParameterSpec);

byte[] encryptedA = cipher.update(A);

byte[] encryptedB = cipher.update(B);

while( true){        
         
    if( blocks > 1 ) {
        encrypted = cipher.update(data);
    }
    else {
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
    blocks--; 
    //write bytes to file
}
```

When encrypting I can see that the vector inside the Cipher is updated after every update() as expected (the last ciphertext is the vector for subsequent updates. for example encryptedA is the vector of the cipher at the time I call update(B)

Decryption code

```
Cipher cipherB = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipherB.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, fileKey, ivParameterSpecB);

byte[] decryptedA = cipherB.update(encryptedA);
byte[] decryptedB = cipherB.update(encryptedB);

while( true){

      if(blocks > 1 ) {
            decrypted = cipherB.update(encryptedBytes);
      }
      else {
            decrypted = cipherB.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
      } 
       blocks--; 
       //write bytes to file  
}
```

What's happening at this point very odd.

The **first call** to cipherB.update(encryptedA) **does nothing at all**. It returns an empty array and doesn't update the vector inside the cipher.
The **second call** to cipherB.update(encryptedB) **returns the value I was expecting from the previous call** ( cipherB.update(encryptedA) which is the original value: A) and sets the vector to the value of encryptedA

Can you spot anything wrong in my approach? Are there any known issues in AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding when using the default SunJCE provider?

Update:
After reading some of the comments, let me add some extra clarification

1. the conditions are around the blocks used for encrypting the payload. the first condition is simple while(true) and the second one is if(blockCount > 1). there's a block counter that's been decreased in every loop. Code updated
2. If A and B are omitted from the encryption/decryption, the file data is properly been decrypted
3. I tried decrypting the direct outcome of the encryption
   for example:

   ```
   cipherB.update(cipher.update(A))
   ```

but I'm still getting the same empty array instead of A

4. I cannot rely on running updates twice, after getting back B by running cipherB.update(encryptedB) something is going wrong and the file data decryption is affected by the vector in the cipher.
   The data I get back is something like

   (12 random bytes)Lorem Ipsum etc

Comment: Provided that `A` and `B` as well as `encryptedA` actually consist of a full block (16 bytes) then this is indeed strange behavior but this shouldn't be a problem. Or at least I don't see a problem with this behavior since you can always call the next `update` and it would be a good practice to do that in order to code defensively. The underlying JCE might change in the future and you should write your code not assuming too much.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The problem is that the `condition` and `other condition` is his while loop may depend on the data being decrypted. In the extreme, the calls to `update()` might return nothing at all(with an AEAD cipher for example) and only the call to `doFinal()` returns anything. OP needs a different design I suspect.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you,please have look at my updated question. point 4

Comment: Provided `encryptedA` and `encryptedB` are full blocks: The first `cipherB.update(encryptedA)` returns nothing, because during decryption _at least a full block_ remains in the buffer. This is due to padding (in the context of CBC): The last block _could_ contain a padding (up to the size of the entire block), which won't be decided till the next `update` / `doFinal`. For the same reason the subsequent `cipherB.update(encryptedB)` returns only the plaintext related to `encryptedA`, `encryptedB` remains in the buffer etc.

Comment: As I said, you cannot rely on specific behavior of the `update` calls. Try looking into CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream. Since you're writing to a file this should be an alternative API where you can read as many bytes as you need from the stream. (I'm still not sure why this is an issue for you.)

Answer (score 1):

The plaintext and ciphertext chunks do not correspond to each other 1 to 1. You need to capture the full output in a byte[] and unpack it yourself.

Comment: Thank you, please have a look at my updated answer. point 3

Answer (score 1):

The `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` mode works on blocks, so the update will return you only "filled" blocks and doFinal will return you the rest. AES is using 128 bit block, so the `update` method returns only multiples of 16 bytes. As well there is a last block with padding. So your assumption `cipherB.update(cipher.update(A))` doesn't work in this case.

I'm not really following what are you trying to achieve by the condition `if(blocks > 1 )`

You could use following code to process cipher blocks (simplified version):

```
  byte[] decrypted = null; 
  byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
  InputStream in = ..;
  for (int bytesRead=in.read(buffer); bytesRead>=0; bytesRead=in.read(buffer)) {
    decrypted = cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    // process the chunk
  }
  decrypted = cipher.doFinal();
  // process the chunk
```

this way it doesn't matter if you process a single block or not.

There are as well "stream ciphers" or modes when the *update* method directly returns encrypted or decrypted chunk regardless of the input size, such as `AES/CTR` mode or `Salsa20` cipher